# Determining the byte size of multisig transaction beforehand knowing the details of the transaction

Tags: raw-transaction, multi-signature

If I know the m of n values of the multisig, the # of inputs (all of which are from the multisig and require m signatures) and outputs and the redeem script, how can I determine the size of the transaction after m signatures?

Comment: @JBaczuk there doesn't seem to be an accepted answer there, nor does the existing answers fully provide an answer.

Comment: @tipu to me it seems that the voted answer in the other question fits and answers your question.  It assumes that `p2sh-multisig` is being redeemed, all pubkeys are compressed (33 bytes per pubkey) and that the signatures produced are 72 bytes each.  If you're asking about segwit specifically (the calculation will be a bit different in that case), then please edit your question.  Otherwise I agree that it's a duplicate.